# Error while generating using proto definition

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I'm using a mac m1 with open jdk 11 and trying to generate using proto definition.

```
openjdk version "11.0.18" 2023-01-17 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.62+17-CA (build 11.0.18+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.62+17-CA (build 11.0.18+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```

I have the following defined in the parent pom.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${protobuf-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <protocArtifact>
            com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.3.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
        </protocArtifact>
        <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
        <pluginArtifact>
            io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.4.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
        </pluginArtifact>
        <clearOutputDirectory>false</clearOutputDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When generating I'm getting the following error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.xolstice.maven.plugins:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.6.1:compile-custom (default) on project com.sample.resource.monitoring.service: Unable to resolve artifact: Missing:
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1) com.google.protobuf:protoc:exe:osx-aarch_64:3.3.0
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]   Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]   Then, install it using the command: 
[ERROR]       mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.google.protobuf -DartifactId=protoc -Dversion=3.3.0 -Dclassifier=osx-aarch_64 -Dpackaging=exe -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]   Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
[ERROR]       mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.google.protobuf -DartifactId=protoc -Dversion=3.3.0 -Dclassifier=osx-aarch_64 -Dpackaging=exe -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]   Path to dependency: 
[ERROR]         1) com.sample:com.sample.resource.monitoring.service:jar:0.0.135-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR]         2) com.google.protobuf:protoc:exe:osx-aarch_64:3.3.0
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1 required artifact is missing.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] for artifact: 
[ERROR]   com.sample:com.sample.resource.monitoring.service:jar:0.0.135-SNAPSHOT
```

As a work around I upgraded protoc to 3.17.3 and gen-grpc-java to 1.49.1. This fixed the issue but conflicts when I integrate with other services. For some of my fellow devs this works without any issue. So far I have not been able to find what's the issue with existing configurations.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: M1 was released in 2020 and you appear to be using `protoc` [v3.3.0](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.3.0) from 2017. I encourage you to consider having the team maintain currency with `protoc` (security, bugs etc.). I suspect your only alternative is to try to compile `protoc` for yourself. See this [issue](https://github.com/os72/protoc-jar/issues/93) from 2021 (!) on support for M1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's known issue: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/7690
but there are also suggestions what to in that case:

1. replace `${os.detected.classifier}` with `osx-x86_64`
2. set maven active profile property `os.detected.classifier` to `osx-x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

I fix with this change:

from:

```
<configuration>
           <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.17.3:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
           <protocArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.40.1:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
</configuration>
```

To:

```
<configuration>
           <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.17.3:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
           <protocArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.53.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
</configuration>
```